# Check if Guava HashBasedTable contains any empty cells

Tags: java, guava, guava-table

I am sending some data around in my application as a Guava HashBasedTable.

I want to implement some validations on the table to make sure it is not missing data in any of its cells. (If a column exists and a row exists, the value at Cell:column/row should be populated.)

I'm looking for a native method to implement something like this but not having much luck.

Tried something like `dataTable.containsValue()` to check for nulls or empty string but it doesn't seem it is initialized in this way.

Any pointers?

Resources: https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html

Comment: The documentation says null isn't supported anyway, so you don't need to bother that, just empty String. But what do you mean here: "Tried something like `dataTable.containsValue()` to check for nulls or empty string but it doesn't seem it is initialized in this way."?

Comment: Hi @Tom, I tried to call `dataTable.containsValue("")` on a table which I know has blank cells. However, it seems the table does not work this way. Cells which have never been populated don't have value `""`

Comment: To clarify, the cells in question are cells which have never had data in them. I hoped these untouched cells would have a value such as `null` or `""` so that they could be easily located with `containsValue()` but it seems that's not the case

Comment: That seems to be a misunderstanding here. Although it is called a table and allows you to use row and column, it isn't actually one, thus there aren't uninitialized value and that's why the class doesn't support a method for your use case. If a row-column-combination can't be found, it returns `null`, so you can iterate throw all rows and columns to search for `null` manually. But you need to know dimension of the table, `HashBasedTable` can't give you that.

Comment: "Untouched cells" do not exist in any way in a Guava table.  If you look through a cellSet, you won't find them; if you look through a Row, you won't find them.  The only way is to loop through the rowKeySet and columnKeySet and check if it contains(row, col).